# How can I properly normalise surround audio to stereo(2 channels)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, stereo, 5.1

This question has been asked before but my query is different and more specific. In MPV player I use this command `af=format=channels=stereo,dynaudnorm` which is like live normalising the audio. However, I want use ffmpeg to output the surround (5.1/7.1) audio to stereo(2 channels) and I'm not sure about what command syntax I should use for this `af=format=channels=stereo,dynaudnorm`

Optional: I would also like to convert dts audio to FLAC or eac3 in the same command and mux it into the same video all in a single command, but this is optional, the main focus is on the above query

Answer (score 0):

`af=format=channels=stereo,dynaudnorm` should be

`-af "aformat=cl=stereo,dynaudnorm"`

Comment: Could you give me the full command?

Comment: This doesn't work at all. FFmpeg doesn't recognise "cl".

Comment: Add -report to the command and rerun. Share report file.